# Group by numbers in MongoDB aggregate framework

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to calculate the number of users who are born in particular years using the following pipeline.

```
{"$group": {"_id": "$birthdayYear", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
```

but what I get is the following where all the years are sum, and Mongo does not have a `$count` function, so what can I do to group the number of users based on the year they're born?

**Sample document**

```
{
    "_id" : "LrN2tAK4rtyhsYFbr",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984,
}
```

/* 1 */

```
{
    "_id" : "birthDayYear",
    "count" : 5550.0
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a document?

Comment: there is a typo in your query according to the sample doc you posted: should be `$birthdayYear` and not `$birthYear`

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted 2 documents into users collections

```
db.users.insert({ "_id" : "LrN2tAK4rtyhsYFbs",     "firstName" : "test",     "lastName" : "1",     "birthdayDay" : 5,     "birthdayMonth" : 8,     "birthdayYear" : 1984})

db.users.insert({ "_id" : "LrN2tAK4rtyhsYFbr",     "firstName" : "test",     "lastName" : "2",     "birthdayDay" : 6,     "birthdayMonth" : 9,     "birthdayYear" : 1984})
```

And run following query

```
db.users.aggregate([{$group: {"_id": "$birthdayYear", count: {$sum:1}} }])
```

And got the result

```
{ "_id" : 1984, "count" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the syntax of your aggregate statement - I believe below shows the desired results:

```
 db.tstso1.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$birthdayYear", count: { $sum: 1 }}}])
```

Results:

```
{ "_id" : 1986, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1985, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 1984, "count" : 6 }
```

Documents:

```
 see.pretty();
{
    "_id" : "LrN2tAK4rtyhsYFbr",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984
}
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984
}
{
    "_id" : "4",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984
}
{
    "_id" : "6",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984
}
{
    "_id" : "7",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1984
}
{
    "_id" : "12",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1985
}
{
    "_id" : "13",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1986
}
{
    "_id" : "14",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1985
}
{
    "_id" : "16",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1986
}
{
    "_id" : "17",
    "firstName" : "abc",
    "lastName" : "",
    "birthdayDay" : 5,
    "birthdayMonth" : 8,
    "birthdayYear" : 1985
}
```